# How to revoke token provided by OAuth from google? NodeJS

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api-nodejs-client

I have connected to google plus from my NodeJS application by using oauth2, but how to revoke token/disconnect? I cant find anything in docs for NodeJS.

Answer (score 6):

You can revoke a token with [`revokeToken`](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/bd13376281a3af6e73fb729ea867950739c3c899/ts/lib/auth/oauth2client.ts#L320-L333) function from `google.auth.OAuth2` object :

```
oauth2Client.revokeToken(token, function(err, body) {

});
```

You also have [`revokeCredentials`](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/bd13376281a3af6e73fb729ea867950739c3c899/ts/lib/auth/oauth2client.ts#L335-L347) function which clear the credential object and revoke the access token inside it :

```
oauth2Client.revokeCredentials(function(err, body) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case access_token expires, revokeToken method returns "Invalid Token Error". At this time we can pass refresh_token (if you have procured it and put it in a persistant storage). So the changes in the code follows as

```
let token = oauth2Client.credentials.refresh_token;   
oauth2Client.revokeToken(token, function(err, body) {
    //Do something here after checking if err is set or not
});
```